# What does the word "it" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> Even if determinism isn't true for everything that happens—even if
>   some things just happen without being determined by causes that were
>   there in advance—**it** would still be very significant if everything we
>   did were determined before we did it. However free you might feel when
>   choosing
>
> [Thomas Nagel - What does it all mean? p.52]

What does the word "it" mean?

Comment: See **it** as an *empty or dummy subject*.    https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/it

Answer (score 4):

'It' is a dummy subject. English clauses which are not imperatives must have a subject. Sometimes we need to use a ‘dummy’ or ‘empty’ or ‘artificial’ subject when there is no subject attached to the verb, and where the real subject is somewhere else in the clause.

[Dummy subjects (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/dummy-subjects)

Comment: Could I replace "if" with "that" without changing its meaning?

Comment: @XVI  Not in this case.  *That* is a pronoun that must relate to something previously-mentioned.  You can, however, replace *it* with *this*: *"This would still be very significant ..."*.